# gdb package not appearing in Cygwin setup

Tags: c, eclipse, gdb, cygwin

I need to write some programs in C, so I've downloaded and installed cygwin and Eclipse Neon cpp.
I've installed the required Cygwin packages and my C programs are compiling and running but I can't debug them because GDB isn't installed.
I get "Error with command: gdb --version" when I try to debug in Eclipse.
I've opened the Cygwin setup again, searched but there's no GDB in the packages ([Picture of the installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKZLz.png)) list. How can I add the GDB package to the Cygwin setup and install it so that Eclipse can use it?
The difference between my question and the one that is suggested is that I entered the setup but can't find the package.
I'm running Windows 10, Eclipse Neon.1a Release 4.6.1 and Cygwin 2.6.0

Thanks

Comment: gdb is available, looks on the full view at select package to see all packages

Comment: Hello, I've added a screenshot of the installation. I can't find the package

Comment: because you are trying to install from the cached file "Install from local Directory" instead than from the server "Install from Internet".

Comment: Thanks for the response, I found it. Now I have another problem with GDB in Eclipse but I'll post that in another question :)